# How To Disable Visual Studio 2012 Lookahead In Find Dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to disable the search lookahead (air quotes) feature (end air quotes) when I'm using the Find Dialog within Visual Studio 2012?  I've searched through all of the editor settings I can find in the Options panel and I'm not seeing anything that might disable this incredibly annoying and unnecessary behaviour.